# Angular Material md-grid-tile width and height become 0 after background-image url change

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I encounter a very strange problem of Angular Material Gird List (1.0.0-rc2 - the latest Angular Material). I have a Grid List with 3 elements with background images. Everything load correctly after the initial page load. I have a delete button in each element. When click, it empty out the background image url value. After I click the delete button and empty the background image url value, the associated grid tile lost its width and height. The inside element just float to the top left and the layout is all broken. Here is codepen to illustrate the problem:

http://codepen.io/hughred22/pen/GpXZgy

As you see after clicking the delete button, the red text will lost its position and float to the top left. If you exam the tile, it has 0 width and height.

Here is the HTML code of the md-grid-list:

```html
<md-grid-list md-cols="6" md-cols-sm="6" md-row-height="1:1" md-gutter="0px" md-gutter-gt-sm="0px" style="background: black;">
  <md-grid-tile md-rowspan="3" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="2" style="background-image: url({{vm.picturesObj[0].photo}}); background-size: cover;" class="top-tile-edit">
    <p style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">The Text which is representing the inside elements. It align center when loaded.</p>
    <md-grid-tile-footer>
      <md-button type="button" class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="vm.deleteAddedPhoto(vm.picturesObj[0].photo)">
        Delete
      </md-button>
    </md-grid-tile-footer>
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile md-rowspan="3" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="2" style="background-image: url({{vm.picturesObj[1].photo}}); background-size: cover;" class="top-tile-edit">
  </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile md-rowspan="3" md-colspan="2" md-colspan-sm="2" style="background-image: url({{vm.picturesObj[2].photo}}); background-size: cover;" class="top-tile-edit">
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```